# Form Authentication against our Active Directory’s LDAP server will always return invalid username/password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, ldap, membership-provider

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. And I am using asp.net membership provider to authentication users against our ldap server using form authentication.

Here is the login action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{


    MembershipProvider domainProvider;

    domainProvider = Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        // Validate the user with the membership system.
        if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {


            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

        }
        else
        {
            //  Response.Write("Invalid UserID and Password");
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

    }

    return View(model);
}
```

And the web.config file where I defined a `<providers>` and a `<connection string>` for ldap:-

```
<providers>
<add name="TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, &#xA;Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="DomainConnectionString"  connectionUsername="*****\administrator" connectionPassword="*****" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
</providers>
```

&

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DomainConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://WIN-SPDev.tgroup.local/OU=Domain Controllers,DC=tgroup,DC=local"/>
       </connectionStrings>
```

But now when a user enters his username/password the `domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)` always return false.

Can anyone advice on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The ValidateUser method may return false when the correct credentials are supplied, under the
>   following circumstances:
>
> 1.The user account was locked out by the directory server because of too many failed logon
>   attempts. The user will not be able to log on until the directory's lockout duration passes.
>
> 2.If the EnablePasswordReset property is true, the user account will be locked if the user supplied
>   a bad password answer too many times. The user's account will unlock after the time specified in
>   the PasswordAnswerAttemptLockoutDuration property has passed.
>
> 3.The user must exist in the container specified in the connection string. Valid credentials are
>   supplied for a user account located in a different container or in a different domain. The user
>   must exist in the container specified in the connection string.

May be you need to enter username as `DOMAIN\username` (see 3rd item)?